# Mysterious dll added to solution (System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll)

Tags: .net, visual-studio, jenkins, dll, msbuild

I'm using `VS2019` to build my solution, and it adds `System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll` to my build files.

There is nothing about `Extensions` in my solution. not in the files, not in the references and not in packages.

I do have `using System.Threading.Tasks` and `using System.Threading` but I don't know how and why it is related.
Also, I couldn't find any information about this dll and what it provides, so I can't check the usage as well.

The issue is, when I use `MSBuild` in Jenkins, it creates everything similar to the `VS2019` build, except for this single dll.

So, my question is:

**how can I know where exactly I use something that brings this dll?**

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you're using `System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask` somewhere in your codebase - either explicit or implicit via a different assembly that requires this type.

If you want to find out which assembly causes this reference, you could listen to the `AssemblyResolve` event at runtime.

Or you expand all nodes in the Solution Explorer - it should be there somewhere.

Comment: I did not find any use of `System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`, not even a DLL. And I tried expanding all nodes in the solution explorer, did not find it there either.

Can you tell me more about the `AssemblyResolve` please?

Comment: See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/resolve-loads

Comment: Thank you, I guess you meant this one: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.assemblyload?view=net-6.0

Anyway, I tried it and it shows all the loaded assemblies, but there is nothing that starts with `System.Threading`